# Reduce update code from many single lines into 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tried to reduce my code so i dont have to repeat myself again.

didnt worked out, getting sql syntax error all time.

My Goal: 1 Update query should update all columns instead of doing it 1,1

```
 <?php
  include 'actions/db_connect.php';


  // Escape user inputs for security
  $car_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['car_id']);
  $carname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['carname']);
  $hp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['hp']);
  $img = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['img']);
  $available = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['available']);

  // Change Values in Database

  $sql = "UPDATE cars SET carname='$carname' WHERE car_id='$car_id'";
  $sql1 = "UPDATE cars SET hp='$hp'  WHERE car_id='$car_id'";
  $sql2 = "UPDATE cars SET img='$img'  WHERE car_id='$car_id'";
  $sql3 = "UPDATE cars SET available='$available' WHERE car_id='$car_id'";
```

I tried this on my new project to get all together in one line but well syntax:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE media
  SET title = $title, publish_date = $publish_date, isbn = $isbn, available = $available,  img = $img,  description = $description, 
  type = $type,  fk_pub_id = $fk_pub_id, fk_auth_id = $fk_auth_id
  WHERE med_id = {$id}';
```

base code for that query is:

```
<?php
  include 'dbconnect.php';

  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['title']);
  $publish_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['publish_date']);
  $isbn = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['isbn']);
  $available = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['available']);
  $img = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['img']);
  $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);
  $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['type']);
  $fk_pub_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fk_pub_id']);
  $fk_auth_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fk_auth_id']);
```

Comment: WARNING: you are open to SQL injection. Use prepared statements to secure your application, escaping strings it not enough. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: iam just learning php - thanks :) iam not at the part of security atm iam just trying to get things working hehe

Comment: Converting to prepared statements may also fix some of your problems, so it may be worth the effort.

Comment: @TomersonJefferson: SQL injection isn't just about security, it's also a common source of bugs.  While you're learning is exactly the right time to learn how to do things in a correct, stable, and secure way.  I'll never understand the defense of "first I want to learn how to do it wrong and write buggy code, I'll learn how to do it right later".

Comment: I have provided an example of how to execute your query in both procedural (what you seem to be using) and object oriented approach. I've also provided links to the documentation. Note that you need to bind your params with the correct datatype (i,d,s,b).

Comment: Are there two questions here? e.g. change `cars` query to be 1 query and make `media` query work

Comment: You might take a look at the VALUES option of `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY` but the most important thing is to secure your data against sql injection

Answer (score 2):

Having no idea whatsoever how your db schema looks like (datatypes etc) it should look something like this:

Object oriented:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE media SET title=?, publish_date=?, isbn=?, available=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $title, $publish_date, $isbn, $available, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Procedural:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE media SET title=?, publish_date=?, isbn=?, available=? WHERE id=?");
mysqli_bind_param($stmt,'ssssi', $title, $publish_date, $isbn, $available, $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

More info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
Notice I did not include the entire query but enough to give you an idea.